# Javascript Regex - How to extract last word before path to image

Tags: javascript, regex

I want to use regex to extract the last word from a file path.  For example, I have:
/xyz/blahblah/zzz/abc-blah/def-xyz-**color**.jpg

I want to extract the "**color**" out of the path.  The path color have different syntax.  The only thing that is consistent is the ending where it is always -color.jpg where color would be any [a-z] word.

Is there an elegant way to do this?

I would really appreciate any help here.  Thanks

Comment: I want to clarify that the path is any length, any size, and has one or more hyphens.  The only thing consistent is the -color.jpg at the end where "color" is the word I want to extract out.  And color is any non-digit word.

Comment: Hey people, I know that sometimes using regular expressions isn't the best idea (parsing HTML, etc), but sometimes they simplify **a lot** the code (like in this case). And sometimes you **need** them (because of requirements, or because the tool you're using to validate something forces you to enter a regex, etc), so do we have to keep saying *Why a regex?* or *Why not _this_ better than a regex?* in cases where it doesn't make much sense?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var matched = /-(\w+).jpg/i.exec('/xyz/blahblah/zzz/abc-blah/def-xyz-color.jpg')[1];
```

Answer (score 3):

Why could you just take substring rather than using regex?

```
var path=" /xyz/blahblah/zzz/abc-blah/def-xyz-color.jpg";
var lastHyphen = path.lastIndexOf("-");
var lastDot = path.lastIndexOf(".");
var extractedValue=path.substring(lastHyphen + 1, lastDot);
```

a more compact version will be

```
var extractedValue=path.substring(path.lastIndexOf("-") + 1, path.lastIndexOf("."));
```

Answer (score 0):

What about

```
-(\w+)\.jpg
```

?

If you don't want to hardcode the extension, you can do:

```
-(\w+)\.\w+\b
```

Of course, that will match lots of things, but I'm assuming the text to be matched will be the url ;)

**Edit:**
It will match two groups, and you need to take only the second one, so just access to the 1st index:

```
var text = '/xyz/blahblah/zzz/abc-blah/def-xyz-color.jpg';
var pattern = /-(\w+)\.\w+\b/;
var match = pattern.exec(text);
alert(match[1]);  // color
```

Or do it in one line like @Ryan suggested.

Comment: thx but this didn't work for me.  It gave me two strings back "-color.jpg" and "color".

Comment: @David What it gave you was two groups: The entire match, and only the color. Let me edit it ;)

Comment: Gotcha.  Thanks Oscar.  I used Ryan's but yours edited one was easier to read for a beginner like me.

Answer (score 0):

Why use regex?

```
var a = '/xyz/blahblah/zzz/abc-blah/def-xyz-color.jpg'
    .split('/').pop()
    .split('-').pop()
    .split('.')[0];

console.log(a);
```

Comment: hmmm.. to be honest, I think I prefer regex in this case. For a coder who knows regular expressions, reading a code with a simple regex (for this purpose) would be much clean and readable than all those pops and splits. I mean, that's the idea, isn't it? You will always be able to do some tweaks to avoid using Regex ;)

Comment: This works!  But will this work for a path with any number of "/" or "-" in between?

Comment: @oscar: Arguable, I prefer to use regex only when absolutely necessary as it incurs extra overhead (quite a bit more expensive than native string functions). And if you're after readability, split it across multiple lines (no pun intended ;)) and it's pretty easy to follow along.

Comment: @david: Yes, it will work as long as you have the format `*-color.ext`. Any number of `/` or `-` prior to that will be ignored.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just

```
var path= "/xyz/blahblah/zzz/abc-blah/def-xyz-color.jpg";
/(?:([^-.]+?)\.[^.]+?$)/i.test(path);
var color = RegExp.$1;
alert(color);
```